# facebook API v2 get cover photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a user his facebook cover, but I can't seem to figure out what te correct url is for that.

I tried using the graph.facebook.com, but that is for a different id (not the scoped one?)

I can get the profile picture via `https://graph.facebook.com/'.$loginInfo->id.'/picture?type=large` but I can't seem to find how to fetch the cover photo.

When i go to `https://graph.facebook.com/username` i get an other id, but both can be used to get the profile picture. and both link to the users his profile page

I'm using a bundle to do the facebook login, and like that I get my id. so how would I get the cover photo?

greetings kiwi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using

```
/me?fields=id,cover
```

as a request? `me` is always referencing the actual user which is contained in the Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the source via an api call.

Graph path: `me?fields=cover`

That JSON result will have an other embedded JSON object called "cover" (redundant, I know), and in that JSON object is a field called "source".

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the userId, you can get the image via JavaScript (or its equivalent in php api) with this call:

```
function getProfileCover(userId) {
  FB.api(
    "/" + userId + "/picture",
    function(response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        facebookMeObject.cover = response.data.url;
      }
    }
  );
}
```